# Get complete list of symbols in helm-lisp-completion-at-point?

Tags: helm, completion

I often use `helm-lisp-completion-at-point` to "search" for elisp symbol names. The problem for me is that if I start the completion with

(line|

it filters the completion candidates to symbols **beginning** with "line". But sometimes I guessed wrong and the symbol does not begin with "line". When I delete the helm input line it will only show the candidates starting with "line".

How can I always get the full list of completion candidates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do this by default, see `(glob-syms (and target pred (all-completions target obarray pred)))` in the code - it's all pre-determined.

But this is a good thing, since pre-narrowing the candidate list
really speeds up the completion.  For example, I have 70k symbols
bound/fbound in my current session - narrowing them to "line" gives
just 12.  Of course, 70k isn't that drastic, but you may get a 0.1s
delay here and there - perceptible if you use the command a lot.

Here's how to patch the function to do what you want (if you decide to accept the slowdown).  The change is `(all-completions target obarray pred)` -> `(all-completions "" obarray pred)`.

```cl
(defun helm-lisp-completion-at-point ()
  "Preconfigured helm for lisp symbol completion at point."
  (interactive)
  (setq helm-lgst-len 0)
  (let* ((target (helm-thing-before-point))
         (beg (car (helm-bounds-of-thing-before-point)))
         (end (point))
         (pred (and beg (helm-lisp-completion--predicate-at-point beg)))
         (loc-vars (and (fboundp 'elisp--local-variables)
                        (ignore-errors
                          (mapcar #'symbol-name (elisp--local-variables)))))
         (glob-syms (and target pred (all-completions "" obarray pred)))
         (candidates (append loc-vars glob-syms))
         (helm-quit-if-no-candidate t)
         (helm-execute-action-at-once-if-one t)
         (enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
    (setq helm-lisp-completion--cache (cl-loop for sym in candidates
                                         for len = (length sym)
                                         when (> len helm-lgst-len)
                                         do (setq helm-lgst-len len)
                                         collect sym))
    (if candidates
        (with-helm-show-completion beg end
          ;; Overlay is initialized now in helm-current-buffer.
          (helm
           :sources (helm-build-in-buffer-source "Lisp completion"
                      :data helm-lisp-completion--cache
                      :persistent-action 'helm-lisp-completion-persistent-action
                      :nomark t
                      :fuzzy-match helm-lisp-fuzzy-completion
                      :persistent-help (helm-lisp-completion-persistent-help)
                      :filtered-candidate-transformer
                      'helm-lisp-completion-transformer
                      :action `(lambda (candidate)
                                 (with-helm-current-buffer
                                   (run-with-timer
                                    0.01 nil
                                    'helm-insert-completion-at-point
                                    ,beg ,end candidate))))
           :input (if helm-lisp-fuzzy-completion
                      target (concat target " "))
           :resume 'noresume
           :buffer "*helm lisp completion*"
           :allow-nest t))
      (message "[No Match]"))))
```

Comment: If you use the patched version, and delete the input you'll get the full list of candidates.

Comment: I edit the question so it is a better match to the answer because the reloading of the helm source seems to be good candidate for a separate  question.